Unit Test for Firebase Rules with firestore.get
I'm struggling to find a way to test security rules for storage with firestore.get().
I create a test environment with the project-id: "project-test":
testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: "project-test",
    firestore: {
        rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8080,
    },
    storage: {
        rules: fs.readFileSync("storage.rules", "utf8"),
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9199
    }
});

I'm adding the a doc for firebase.get():
    await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {
        const theirProfileAdmin = doc(context.firestore(), `/profiles/${theirId}`);
        await setDoc(theirProfileAdmin, {tokens: {[myId]: true}});
    });

I'm try to read this document with firebase.get() but its always null.
Does not work:
firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/profiles/$(myId)).data.tokens[toCheckUid] == true;
firestore.get(/projects/project-test/databases/(default)/documents/profiles/$(myId)).data.tokens[toCheckUid] == true;
firestore.get(/project-test/databases/(default)/documents/profiles/$(myId)).data.tokens[toCheckUid] == true;

With project-id: "project" it works and also in prod system. Any idea how is the correct way to define the url for a unit test?
